# Why does my program give wrong answer for a test case?

Tags: greedy

[Codeforces problem 1A](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1/A)

My solution is giving the wrong output for test case 16(1000000000 1000000000 192). I think this is because I have selected a less suitable data type. Judge's log is given below:

```
Test: #16, time: 0 ms., memory: 0 KB, exit code: 0, checker exit code: 1, verdict: WRONG_ANSWER
Input
1000000000 1000000000 192
Output
-270385980
Answer
27126743055556
Checker Log
wrong answer 1st numbers differ - expected: '27126743055556', found: '-270385980'
```

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
long long int n,m,a,b;
int main()
{
    cin>>n>>m>>a;
    b=((n+a-1)/a)*((m+a-1)/a);
    cout<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

Kindly guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Try to use long long as your answer will as large as 10^18.

Comment: Tried it.I am still getting the same incorrect output.

Comment: Maybe you should change all the int into long long in you program. Would you should me the code?

Comment: Is long long a data type?It is giving the expected output with that.Thanks.

Comment: yes. long long is always 64-bit, int is 32-bit, long is 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine.
Have a look at this http://codeforces.com/contest/1/submission/6514118